# Django - Issue having two different forms within one view and calling functions

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have two different forms which I want to display in one view. When I have something like the following then the form will go through and the information will successfully be updated...

```
form1 = Form1(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)
form2 = Form2(request.POST, instance=list)
if form1.is_valid():
    form1.save()
    return redirect('/dashboard/')
else:
    return render(request, 'detail-edit.html', {'form1':form1,'form2':form2})
```

However when I change the if statement to include the second form:

```
if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
    form1.save() and form2.save()
    return redirect('/dashboard/')
```

then this doesn't update any of the information for the models.

Is it possible to call is_valid() / save() with two forms at the same time? 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Model.save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) returns nothing; `None`. The None is falsy value when used as a predicate.

So, `form2.save()` is not called because of short-circuit. See [`and`, `or` operator documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not).

```
>>> def save_a():
...     print('a')
...     # return None
... 
>>> def save_b():
...     print('b')
...     # return None
... 
>>> save_a() and save_b()    # with `and`
a

>>> save_a()    # without `and`
a
>>> save_b()
b
```

You need to replace the following line:

```
form1.save() and form2.save()
```

with:

```
form1.save()
form2.save()
```